# How to create another column that contains an operation based on two different values of a same categorical column in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

My data frame looks like this:

```
Person  Payment_Type   Amount  Place
Adam     C               500     X
Adam     D               200     X
Adam     C               80      Y
Adam     D               30      Y
Bob      C               100     Y
Bob      D               20      Y
```

I want to create a column `Final_Payment` such that it is equal to `C-D` for every place against every person. For example:

```
Person    Place    Final_Payment
Adam        X         300
Adam        Y         50
Bob         Y         80
```

Now, I've tried to `groupby` the Amount and the Place by writing:

`sample=sample.groupby(['Place']).agg({'Amount':'sum'})`
but this only gives me a dataframe with Places and the sum of all Amounts corresponding to it. I know this is wrong.

The logic that I've come up with so far is:

```
for Person, Place in Dataframe
   Final_Payment= Amount at C - Amount at D
end
```

and I honestly cannot figure out a way to code this part. How can I arrive at that final column against every place & person? I am really stumped at this point.

I'd genuinely appreciate any help I can get!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html) and then get the difference , then rename as you wish:

```
m = df.pivot_table(index=['Person','Place'],columns='Payment_Type',values='Amount')
out = (m['C']-m['D']).rename('Final_Payment').reset_index()
```

---

```
print(out)

  Person Place  Final_Payment
0   Adam     X          300.0
1   Adam     Y           50.0
2    Bob     Y           80.0
```

This is how the pivoted df looks like:

```
print(m)

Payment_Type    C    D
Person Place          
Adam   X      500  200
       Y       80   30
Bob    Y      100   20
```

Comment: Pivot table! Thank you. Thank you!